# possible to write razor code in javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can I write my razor code in javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("test");

        @if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                alert(item);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm getting a error that alert is not defined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("test");
        @if (Model != null) {            
            foreach (var item in Model) {
                @:alert(item);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Since you are inside the razor code block, you need to tell razor `alert()` is not a part of razor code block via `@:`

Alternatively, you can use `<text>` element.

```
<text>
   alert(item);
</text>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
     <text>
     alert(item);
     </text>
}
```